# Filling in missing values in a data.table by reference

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a data.table with missing values and a reference data.table:

```
dt <- data.table(id = 1:5, value = c(1, 2, NA, NA, 5))

   id value
1:  1     1
2:  2     2
3:  3    NA
4:  4    NA
5:  5     5

ref <- data.table(id = 1:4, value = c(1, 2, 98, 99))

   id value
1:  1     1
2:  2     2
3:  3    98
4:  4    99
```

How would I fill the column `value` of `dt` by using the matching `id` in the two data.tables,
so that I get the following data.table?

```
   id value
1:  1     1
2:  2     2
3:  3    98
4:  4    99
5:  5     5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a join `on` the 'id' and assign (`:=`) the value column from 'ref' (`i.value`) to that in 'dt'

```
library(data.table)
dt[ref, value := i.value, on = .(id)]
dt
#   id value
#1:  1     1
#2:  2     2
#3:  3    98
#4:  4    99
#5:  5     5
```

---

If we don't want to replace the original non-NA elements in the 'value' column

```
dt[ref, value := fcoalesce(value, i.value), on = .(id)]
```

Comment: Ah, of course!  I knew it was something simple like this.  Thanks a lot, akrun!!

Comment: Could you tell me what "i.value" means? And "on = .(id)" simply means to use the column named "id" for matching rows, right?

Comment: @johnc th  `on = .(id)` is the joining column `on` that 'id' (it is ssimilar to `by = ` in `merge` or `left_join`.  It will return the rows where there is a corresponding match for 'id' in both datasets.  As the column names are same for 'value', the `i.` helps in identfying the column from second dataset

Comment: Does that mean the `i.` can be replaced by any other string?  Could you point to where I can read more about the `i.` and `on = .(id)`?  Thank you, again, for all your help.

Comment: @johnc I meant that if you ref column names was `value1` or any other name othere than 'value', you could simply use that name instead of `i.`, but `i.` would also work.  It is to uniquely identify that column

Comment: @johnC I would say the vignettes of data.table could be one place you can read about it